# How can I renumber a field inside a collection of objects?

Tags: c#

Given this class:

```
public class TS
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public string t { get; set; }
}
```

I have a variable `ts` that contains a list of `TS` objects. The `TS` objects 
have value of `i` varies between 10 and 99. I don't need to reorder the objects. Just change the value of `i`.

```
IList<TestQuestionHeaderBase> ts;
```

How can I create a new list of `TS` objects with 
numbers that start at 1 and increase until the last object?

Comment: A new list of the old, mutated objects or a (new) list of new objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
ts = ts.Select((x,i) => new TS { i=i+1, t=x.t }).ToList();
```

it will create new list of objects indexed from 1 to count using [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from LINQ (creating new objects also). Or without creating new objects and keeping list (but you need to change it from `IList` to `List`):

```
var i=0;
ts.ForEach(x=> x.i=i++);
```

Comment: I tried the second solution but it gives an error saying ts does not contain a ForEach method.

Comment: @Alan if you are using `IList` it should contain `ForEach`

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' 
accepting a first argument of type
 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<TS>' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  When I hover over ts it says it's an ILIST<TS> but still gives me this error.

Comment: @Alan sorry I've checked it in project where I have included `NHibernate` and it has extension for `IList` making `ForEach` available

Comment: I used your first example now so all's okay. Thanks